# how to solve NoClassDefFoundError in cucumber test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

i am using eclipse as a IDE and Selenium web driver. i am trying to run test in cucumber-JVM.
when i am run test it show me "NoClassDefFoundError ". can anyone help me to solve my problem. all relevant jar files are build in to project file.

Comment: Share the code and jars name with version that you have used.

Comment: stack trace of the error? what class can't it find?

Comment: error show like below:                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:cucumber/deps/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConverterRegistry
 at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:68)
 at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:56)
 at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:52)
 at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: i am using cucumber-core-1.1.4.jar, cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar , cucumber-java-1.1.4.jar , cucumber-junit-1.1.4 , gherkin-2.9.3 , gherkin-jvm-deps-1.0.2 , junit-4.10

Comment: I would recommend you to update your question with your dependencies. Also it would be worth while to check by adding xstream dependency. Also I would recommend to update JUnit to 4.11 and try.

Answer (score 4):

Add cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar file into your build path. You can download cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar file from [cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.3/)

Answer (score 0):

If the NoClassDefFoundError is coming from either XmlPullParser or dom4j/element
u need to install this Eclipse Plugin/Update:
Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software…
http://cucumber.github.com/cucumber-eclipse/update-site