# When I'm running TestRunner class using junit Cucumber , i 'm getting Below error:

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-junit

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:23)
```

I have used cucumber-java-4.2.0,cucumber-junit-4.2.0,cucumber-core-4.2.0,junit-4.12, and gherkin 2.1.12.

And, when used gherkin 5.1.0, getting below error"

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
io/cucumber/datatable/dependency/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType
at io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableType.<init>(DataTableType.java:78)
at io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableTypeRegistry.<init> 
(DataTableTypeRegistry.java:27)
at io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry.<init>(TypeRegistry.java:22)
at
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771066/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-exception-while-running-cucumber-test-using-junit . Mismatched versions might be an issue.

Comment: I have already tried those solutions But, didn't work for me.:(

Comment: you just need to add dependency for junit 4.12, cucumber-junit 4.2.0, cucumber-java 4.2.0. gherkin etc are downloaded automatically as dependencies. Check the "Dependencies Heirarchy" tab for the POM if u are on eclipse

Comment: Tried the above one: getting                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
   o/cucumber/datatable/dependency/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType
 at io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableType.<init>(DataTableType.java:78)
 at io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableTypeRegistry.<init>\

Comment: Gherkin v5.1.0 is getting added to pom dependies. Is it causing the issue..

Comment: do u have the datatable 1.1.7 jar and datatable-dependencies 1.1.7 jar in the maven dependencies downloaded automatically?

Comment: If not then delete the local repository "io.cucumber" and build project again. Else add the dependency explicitly to the  pom - <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Yes. those got added to pom dependencies

Comment: The "JavaType" class should be inside the datatable-dependencies 1.1.7 jar

Comment: I deleted the repository and built it once again. Now, error is not coming but getting 
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.132s even though i have scenario and step implementations..This is my feature file:      Feature: Application Login

  Scenario Outline: Home Page Default Login.
    Given User is on NetBanking Landing Page
    When User login into application with username and password
    And clicks on submit buttton
    Then Home page is displayed

Comment: Thanks @Grasshopper.. working for me after re-build of project.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the jar version too high, you can change a low version.
such as change `4.3.1` to `4.0.0`.

Comment: Please use english lanugage only.