# Error on running Test Runner class - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, pom.xml

**Error when running the TestRunner file**

```
Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Reporter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/
```

Updated all the dependencies to current versions

**POM.xml**

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>latest</groupId>
      <artifactId>corp</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>corp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <!--    <configuration>
        <includes>
        <excludes>**/*TestRunnertest.java</excludes>
        </includes>
        </configuration> -->
        </plugin>

                  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <source>1.8</source>
                      <target>1.8</target>
                       <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>          
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>   

      </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of research would have helped you as
It's already been [noticed](https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-cucumber/issues/9)

This issue came due to an incompatible combination of selenium and gherkin
dependency. Try changing the gherkin dependency version this issue will be
resolved.
Here are the suggested versions that might help you

> use cucumber 2.4.0 and gherkin 5.1.0

and do check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771066/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-exception-while-running-cucumber-test-using-junit) as well.